# Transaction not working with Web API .net core 2.2

Tags: entity-framework, transactions, ef-core-2.2, webapi

I have a async web API that has services and a connection to the db using an EF context.
In one of the services, where I inject the context using DI I want to make a simple transactional service, like:

```
public async Task<int> ServiceMethod()
{
    using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
         await context.Table1.AddAsync(new Table1());
         await context.SaveChangeAsync();

         CallOtherservice(context);
         await context.SaveChangeAsync();

         transaction.Commit();   
    }
}

CallOtherService(Context context)
{
     await context.Table2.AddAsync();
}
```

I have now mocked CallOtherService() to throw an exception and I expect nothing to be commited, but it looks like changes to Table1 persist, amid the transaction trhat should stop them. I have tried calling Rollback() in a try catch statement and using a TransactionScope() instead, but both were useless. Also, I have noticed that after calling .BeginTransaction(), context.Database.CurrentTransaction is null, which I consider a bit weird.

EDIT:
the method that I test:

```
public async Task<int> AddMatchAsync(Models.Database.Match match)
        {
            //If match is null, nothing can be done
            if (match == null)
                return 0;
            else
            {
                using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //If the match already exists, return its id
                        var dbId = await ExistsMatchAsync(match.HomeTeam.Name, match.AwayTeam.Name, match.Time);
                        if (dbId > 0)
                        {
                            log.Info($"Found match with id {dbId}");
                            return dbId;
                        }

                        //add computable data
                        match = await AttachMatchName(match);
                        match.Season = CommonServices.toSeason(match);

                        // Prepare the relational entities accordingly
                        match = PrepareTeamsForAddMatch(match).Result;
                        match = PrepareLeagueForAddMatch(match).Result;

                        //add the match and save it to the DB
                        await context.Matches.AddAsync(match);
                        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        log.Info($"Successfully added a new match! id: {match.Id}");

                        // Create new TeamLeagues entities if needed
                        leaguesService.CreateTeamLeaguesForNewMatchAsync(context, match);
                        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

                        scope.Complete();
                        return match.Id;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error($"Error adding match - Rolling back: {ex}");
                        throw;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

and the test:

````
        [Test] 
        public void AddMatchSaveChangesTransaction()
        {
            //Arrange
            var exceptiontext = "This exception should prevent the match from being saved";
            var leagueServiceMock = new Mock<ILeaguesService>();
            leagueServiceMock.Setup(p => p.CreateTeamLeaguesForNewMatchAsync(It.IsAny<InFormCoreContext>(),It.IsAny<Match>()))
                .Throws(new Exception(exceptiontext));

            leagueServiceMock.Setup(p => p.GetLeagueAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
                .ReturnsAsync((string name) => new League{Id = 1, Name = name });

            var match = new Match
            {
                HomeTeam = new Team { Name = "Liverpool" },
                AwayTeam = new Team { Name = "Everton" },
                League = new League { Name = "PL", IsSummer = true },
                Time = DateTime.UtcNow,
                HomeGoals = 3,
                AwayGoals = 0
            };
            var mcount = context.Matches.Count();

            //Act
            var matchService = new MatchesService(context, leagueServiceMock.Object, new LogNLog(), TeamsService);

            //Assert
            var ex = Assert.ThrowsAsync<Exception>(async () => await matchService.AddMatchAsync(match));
            Assert.AreEqual(ex.Message, exceptiontext); 

            Assert.AreEqual(mcount, context.Matches.Count(), "The match has been added - the transaction does not work");
        }`
```
````

Comment: Please try to develop a short, self-contained repro.  You will discover that the code you posted does not produce the behavior you describe.

Comment: I have one. This is part of my service and I unit test this exact issue out of it. I have added the tested method in the description

Comment: I ran that code and couldn't repro.  Can you share the model and test code.

Comment: I have added the method under test and the test itself in the description